# List, view workflow approval status from multiple workflows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, workflow

I have a list with 2 OOTB SharePoint approval workflows configured. One we'll call Engineering Approval and the other Management approval. The Management Approval was recently created to send approvals to a different group of people.

In my list view, only the Engineering Approval (status) column is available. I cannot find anywhere to add the Management Approval (status) column. Where is it? Both OOTB approvals use the same Tasks and Workflow History.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add the Workflow Status column by Modifying View.

Click **Library Settings** > Select the **View** where you want to display workflow Status > Select the Workflow name under **Columns** tab and give the order position number > Click **OK**

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I came to realize that I couldn't see the workflow status because I already had too many lookup columns. I had to adjust the webapp throttling settings and it finally appeared.